# What does this symbol mean: $ℝ^p$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, notation

in my work I have encountered this definition and I am not sure what it means:

[image]

if x is a vector of length n. what does the R superscript p mean?
For context see the link and scroll to the SVC subsection:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html

Comment: probably a typo, but context would help.

Comment: it looks like there are $n$ vectors, each having $p$ components

Comment: The vectors are not of length $n$. As @J.W.Tanner points out, your training set consists of $n$ vectors and each of those is in $\mathbb R^p$ which means they are tuples of length $p$.

Comment: ah okay, thanks everyone! makes much more sense now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $n$ training vectors, indexed by $i\in\{1,...,n\}$.

The vectors are in $\mathbb R^p$, which means they each have $p$ (real number) components.

$\mathbb R^p$ is the [real coordinate space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_coordinate_space) of $p$ dimensions, which consists of $p$-tuples of real numbers.